# MomentJS getting previous dates relative to today

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Is there anyway to get the days past the current day using MomentJS?

For example suppose it is **January 5, 2018**, how would I get the previous dates from **January 1, 2018** through to **January 5, 2018** ?

My current code looks like this:

```
const monthArr = [];
const dayArr= [];
const currentDate = moment(new Date()).format("DD");

for (let i = 0; i < +currentDate; i++) {
  const month = moment(new Date())
    .subtract(i, "day")
    .format("MMYYYY");

  const day = moment(new Date())
    .subtract(i, "day")
    .format("MMDDYYYY");

  console.log("month" + month);
  console.log("day" + day);

  let monthObj = {};
  let dailyObj = {};

  monthArr.push(
    (monthObj = {
      data: {
        [month]: Object.assign({}, document)
      }
    })
  );
  day.push(
    (dailyObj = {
      data: {
        [day]: Object.assign({}, document)
      }
    })
  );

  monthly(user_id, monthArr[i]) &&
  daily(user_id, dayArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: `moment().subtract(1, 'day')`

Comment: Can I do this on a loop setting like i as the 1 mention above?

Comment: You can :) you can replace 1 with your loop variable, for example

Comment: Do you mind if I edit the post and post my code ? @andrey

Comment: I do not mind, it is your post

Comment: Edited  code above @Andrey :)

Comment: Its working already. Thanks @Andrey

Comment: So is there any point in this question remaining?

Comment: The code seems very inefficient, it creates 2 new Dates on each iteration (so up to 62 Dates at the end of a month) when only one is needed in total. What is expected from `Object.assign({}, document)`? Why the assignment to *monthObj* and *dailyObj*, which are not used for anything? What do the *monthly* and *daily* functions do? Where does *user_id* come from? Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The code in the OP seems very inefficient and far more complex than required.

To generate a series of formatted strings for dates from today to the start of the month only needs one Date and some very simple arithmetic and formatting. It really doesn't need a library nor any date arithmetic, e.g.

```js
// Pad single digit number with leading zero
function pad(n){
  return (n < 10? '0' : '') + n;
}

var today = new Date(),
    year = today.getFullYear(),
    month = pad(today.getMonth() + 1),
    day,
    i = today.getDate();

do {
  day = pad(i);
  console.log(`Month: ${month + year}`);
  console.log(`Day: ${month + day + year}`);
} while (--i)
```

There are a number of other issues with your code, but they're not directly related to the question.